# Running the script in the same tab and window

Tags: vba, vbscript

how to run this script over and over again (For example 10 times) in one window and on the same tab?

```
list = Array("example.com")
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True


For Each url In list
  ie.Navigate url
  While ie.ReadyState <> 4
  Wend
  wscript.sleep 100000  

Next
```

Comment: You edit the for loop to do this using iteration count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Const RepeatCount = 10

Dim i As Integer

List = Array("example.com")
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True

For i = 1 To RepeatCount

    For Each URL In List
        ie.Navigate URL
        While ie.ReadyState <> 4
        Wend
        wscript.sleep 100000

    Next

Next
```